# Display Splash Screen while RecyclerView is loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, splash-screen

I am developing an app, which fetches data from a server (using I am developing an app, which fetches data from a server (using **volley**), creates objects with these data and displays these data in `textViews`, using a `ReyclerView`. **What I want to achieve**, is displaying a `Splash-Screen` while those data are being downloaded **and** loaded into the `textViews`, by `RecyclerView.adapter`.

I have been searching for the past hour, but I couldn't find a concrete solution. One thing I thought, was creating the `Splash-Screen` as a `fragment` and **not** as an a activity and displaying it while my `mainActivity` is loading. Any ideas?

Comment: don't you want to use progress dialogue?

Comment: @farhana No, I want the splash screen to cover the whole screen when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

you must have asynctask to fetch data from the server. you can fetch data in splash screen and in onPostExecute of the asyntask you can navigate from splash to Recyleview Screen.

Comment: As you can see, I am using volley.

Comment: yeah then you can do it in onResponse method

Comment: I know I can, but the question is how. Using a fragment or sth else?

Comment: Show SplashActivity first then Make volley request in onCreate of SplashActivity and then in onResponse navigate to Recyclerview Screen using intent. I hope you understand

Comment: The problem is not with the volley request, but the time it takes for the adapter to populate the views. Thanks anyway.